MYSQL Join 2 Columns to one column with different values
I have a problem while trying left join one column from one table, because i need 2 columns consult the name by the id
I keep trying and sometimes get null results or the same in origin and destination, how is it the correct way to have the correct result
i have this MYSQL QUERY:

SELECT ORDER.id, ORDER.responsable, ORDER.date, ORDER.state, LOCATION.name as destination, LOCATION.name as origin FROM ORDER LEFT JOIN LOCATION ON destination = LOCATION.id;

With this result:



destination
origin




HOUSE
HOUSE


HOUSE
HOUSE



I expect something like this:



destination
origin




HOUSE
WORK


HOUSE
WORK



On DB is like this:



destination
origin




0
1


0
1




You need to mention the table twice, like ... L1.name as destination, L2.name as origin FROM order LEFT JOIN location L1 ON destionation = L1.id LEFT JOINB location L2 ON origin = l2.id.

The locations are from one same table, if I join 2 times I have the error "locations is not unique".

No, you won't, because I assigned an alias to each one.  Did you try that?  It will work.  You just refer to L1 and L2 instead of using the name "location".

BTW ORDER is a reserved word and should be backticked..
